# Begriff "Namensreaktion"

Tags: genitive

In der Chemie bezeichnet das Wort "Namensreaktion" den Name irgendeiner chemischen Reaktion. Aber ich verstehe die Bildung des Worts nicht. Es handelt sich offensichtlich um ein Genitiv, aber mir scheint, dass es umgekehrt ist. Sollte es nicht "Reaktionsname" sein, das heisst der Name der Reaktion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So wie ich das verstehe, wird *Namens*reaktion verwendet, um solche Reaktionen von denen abzugrenzen, die keinen Namen tragen.

[WP](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Namensreaktionen)

> "Namensreaktionen sind Reaktionen und Reaktionsmechanismen in der organischen Chemie, die bekannt genug sind oder häufig genug verwendet werden, um einen Namen zu tragen."

*Reaktionsname* wiederum wäre der Name einer bestimmten Reaktion aber nicht die Reaktion selbst.

Answer (score 4):

Bin jetzt kein Chemiker, aber "Reaktionsname" wäre, wie du richtig schreibst, der **Name** der Reaktion.

Eine "Namensreaktion" ist jedoch eine **Reaktion** (und nicht der Name einer Reaktion wie du annimmst), und zwar eine Reaktion die einen Namen trägt.

Ich sehe bei der Bildung des Wortes nichts ungewöhnliches. Der zweite Teil , "Reaktion", beschreibt worum es sich handelt und wird durch den ersten Teil, "Namens" (also eine Reaktion mit Namen) näher erläutert.